# Python - shapely: Iterating with method "difference" return unexpected result

Tags: python, polygon, difference, shapely

I'm actually working with shapely on python.

Here is the things:

I have one big polygon, let say

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
LAND = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 20), (20, 20), (20, 0)])
```

and I have a list of random polygon generate with

```
import random
def generate_polygons(box_size=10, amount=15):
    """
    A function that generate an amount of polygon randomly
    in a square of size = box_size
    """
    polygons = []
    for i in range(amount):
        x = random.randint(0, box_size - 2)
        y = random.randint(0, box_size - 2)
        dx = 2
        dy = 2
        polygons.append(Polygon([(x, y), (x, y+dy), (x+dx, y+dy), (x+dx, y)]))
    return polygons
```

I want to make the difference between the LAND and the list of polygons

```
diff = LAND
polygons = generate_polygons(20, 15)

for polygon in polygons:
    diff = diff.difference(polygon)
```

Let's plot the result
Here are the polygons:

```
FIG, AXS = plt.subplots()

if (isinstance(polygons, shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon)):
    X, Y = polygons.exterior.xy
    AXS.fill(X, Y, 'b')
else:
    for polygon in polygons:
        X, Y = polygon.exterior.xy
        AXS.fill(X, Y, 'b')

plt.show()
```

Here is the diff:

```
FIG, AXS = plt.subplots()

if (isinstance(diff, shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon)):
    X, Y = diff.exterior.xy
    AXS.fill(X, Y, 'r', alpha=0.5)
else:
    for polygon in diff:
        X, Y = polygon.exterior.xy
        AXS.fill(X, Y, 'r', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[polygon in blue, diff in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t8NP.png)

I don't understand why It give me this result, anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The final answer is that Shpely DOES the operation but pyplot can't plot it !